# ¿Se puede hacer restauraciones de base de datos con un contrab? SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo esta situación , tengo un sistema que me arroba los backup de una base de datos a un directorio por el cual tengo acceso por FTP. Y requiero usar el ultimo backup para correr unas querys en el SQL Server, mi duda es ¿si hago un codigo que me extraiga el archivo del directorio por FTP en algun directorio deseando puedo hacer una consulta SQL que restaure la base de datos el archivo .bak que tenga?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-backup-from-a-device-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Si, si se puede.